# wkhtmltopdf Custom header and footers with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

Anyone able to use wkhtmltopdf custom header and footer with their ASP.NET MVC? I need your help. I see that wkhtmltopdf is updated and supports some new [functionality](http://madalgo.au.dk/%7Ejakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html) (as of v0.10.0) for header and footer. What I need is close to `--header-html <url>` but not exactly.

I need to render a partial view as a header. `--header-html <url>` requires a link to an html and then some script in that html file. How can I replace that with my partial view? Since my partial view does not have a direct link I cannot seem to figure out what my options are. I can render the partial view and assign the html code to a string but then how would I use it?

Any other thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to capture the HTML from a partial view (try a search for MVC Response Capture).

Then write the HTML to a temporary location on disk and pass the location of the temporary HTML file in the arguments to wkhtmltopdf:

```
try { 
    ...
    var headerDocumentLocation = saveLocation + documentName + "-h.html"

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(headerDocumentLocation , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))) {
        sw.Write(headerHtml);
    }
    ...
    Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            Arguments = "--header-html " + headerDocumentLocation + <other args>,
            FileName = <location of wkhtmltopdf>,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
         };
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    ...
} finally { 
    if (File.Exists(headerDocumentLocation)) {
        File.Delete(headerDocumentLocation);
    }
}
```

This has worked quite well for me.

Comment: This definitely is a valid solution that I thought of except seems a little bit hackish which is why I decided not to go with it. I am trying out a method where I have a header method in my controller which returns a view just for the header and on wkhtmltopdf arguments I link directly to that controller action and I get an empty blue background on the header. No idea why this doesn'y work. Seems like a viable solution. Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.